# Не отображается подменю при нажатии на пункт списка

Tags: javascript, html

При клике на пункт 1, `.sub-menu` появляется, но при клике на пункт 3 - нет. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

```js
document.querySelector('.menu-item-has-children').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.menu-item-has-children').classList.toggle('open');
  document.querySelector('.sub-menu').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.open .active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="">Пункт 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Подпункт 1</li>
      <li>Подпункт 2</li>
      <li>Подпункт 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
    <a href="">Пункт 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="">Пункт 3</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Подпункт 1</li>
      <li>Подпункт 2</li>
      <li>Подпункт 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у Вас JS, но не jQuery, и `document.querySelector('.menu-item-has-children')` находит только первый такой элемент, которому и назначает обработчик.

Нужно или использовать `querySelectorAll` и, перебирая коллекцию, назначить отдельно каждому элементу обработчик, или делегировать обработчик списку `<ul>` и проверять какой элемент был нажат и отталкиваться от него. В примере ниже использован второй подход.

```js
document.querySelector('ul').onclick = function(ev) {
let listItem = ev.target.closest('.menu-item-has-children');
  if (!listItem) return
  listItem.classList.toggle('open');
  listItem.querySelector('.sub-menu').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.sub-menu { display: none; }
.open .active { display: block; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Пункт 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Подпункт 1</li>
      <li>Подпункт 2</li>
      <li>Подпункт 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
    <a href="#">Пункт 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Пункт 3</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Подпункт 1</li>
      <li>Подпункт 2</li>
      <li>Подпункт 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> А как можно сделать что бы второй закрывался, когда первый открыт? Что бы нельзя было чтобы оба пункта меню были открыты

```js
document.querySelector('ul').onclick = function(ev) {
  let listItem = ev.target.closest('.menu-item-has-children');
  if (!listItem) return
  let subMenu;
  this.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children').forEach(el => {
    if (el != listItem) el.classList.toggle('open', false);
    el.querySelector('.sub-menu').classList.toggle('active', false);
  });
  listItem.classList.toggle('open');
  listItem.querySelector('.sub-menu').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.sub-menu { display: none; }
.open .active { display: block; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Пункт 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Подпункт 1</li>
      <li>Подпункт 2</li>
      <li>Подпункт 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom">
    <a href="#">Пункт 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Пункт 3</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Подпункт 1</li>
      <li>Подпункт 2</li>
      <li>Подпункт 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Пункт 4</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Подпункт 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="#">Пункт 5</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Подпункт 1</li>
      <li>Подпункт 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А как можно сделать что бы второй закрывался, когда первый открыт? Что бы нельзя было чтобы оба пункта меню были открыты

Comment: @КонстантинЖевжик: дополнил ответ. Проверяйте.

Comment: Огромное спасибо